# Changing normal values in dataview

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-3.5, dataview

I have a dataview with some columns:

```
<Columns>  
    <asp:BoundField DataField="report_type" HeaderText="Report Type"   
        SortExpression="report_type" />  
    <asp:BoundField DataField="comments" HeaderText="Comments"   
        SortExpression="comments" />  
    <asp:BoundField DataField="anonymouse" HeaderText="anonymouse"   
        SortExpression="anonymouse" />  
    <asp:BoundField DataField="user" HeaderText="Reported by"   
        SortExpression="user" />  
</Columns>
```

I will be getting rid of the anonymouse column from the screen, so I just added it here for demo purposes.

The anonymouse column has either a `1` or a `0`.  If it is a `1`, I need to set the text in the user column to `private`, and if the anonymouse column is a `0`, it should show the users name as normal.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with RowDataBound

```
void Control_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {

    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
      if(e.Row.Cells[3].Text == "1")
      {
         e.Row.Cells[4].Text = ""; // erase the value of cell
         //You can use also to cell : Attributes["style"] = "display:none";


      }
      else
      {
        .... 
      }
  }
```

}

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.  I have updated the question to display the code.

Comment: because you have changed the scope, preference is to create new question

Comment: your need was erase another cell based on specific cell

Comment: Not sure how I've changed the scope, as it's the same problem, the same question, just updated based on your answer?

Comment: but you must create another question because , my answer was validated on your first need, and if you change your question, my answer risk to loose her vote , have you inderstood

Comment: it's easy to create another question

Comment: The answer did not work when I tried it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16237/discussion-between-oshirowanen-and-candie)

Comment: because you have changed your scope it's easy

Comment: I couldn't get it to work using your method, so I ended up changing the values directly from SQL.

Comment: my method answer to set null value to column 4 when column 3 is equals to 1

Comment: Which I tried, but it didn't work.